# 404: Not Found on PDF embed in HTML

Tags: html, pdf

I am trying to embed a local PDF file into a basic HTML page. I've tried using `iframe` and `embed` but the issue still persists.

This is what I have in my `body`:

```
<body>
    
    <div class="messages">
        <input placeholder="Message" id="messageInput" />
    </div>
    <button onclick="prevPage()">Prev Page</button>
    <button onclick="nextPage()">Next Page</button>
    <button onclick="backToTop()">Top</button>
    
    <embed src="/Users/.../Documents/.../.../.../rach2.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></embed>
  
</body>
```

I believe the culprit lies in the file path, so I tried using both absolute and relative, but still did not work. I am using Chrome and on MacOS

[image]

Comment: I just tried `file:///` like I usually did in iOS development, didn't work. 
`smb:///` had a response though, but doesn't launch the file

Comment: Still doesn't work, I will keep looking for solutions, thank you for your time. Appreciate it

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for [all self-closing HTML tags](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/syntax.html#start-tags).